# Changing the prefix of \chapter

Tags: chapters, appendices

New to latex, want to change the prefix of `\chapter` command from Chapter to Appendix and numbering from number to alphabet.

New

### APPENDIX A

Old

### CHAPTER A

Comment: Which `documentclass` are you using? The `book` class actually calls them "Appendices", not "Chapters".

Comment: I vote to close as unclear. The answer might help, but who knows. It is not helpful for any other user.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\renewcommand\chaptername{APPENDIX}` after `\appendix`.